# ошибка exception in thread "main" java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java

При компиляции выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   laba1.Laba1.showTable(Laba1.java:37) at
>   laba1.Laba1.main(Laba1.java:178)
>   C:\Users\Anna\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 21 seconds)

Код программы:

```
 package laba1;
     import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Laba1 {
private Connection con;

    public boolean setConnection(String name, String pass) {//устанавливаем соединение с базой,передаем свой логин и пароль
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@DESKTOP-34UDS4O:1522:XE [SYS as sysdba on ANONYMOUS]",name, pass);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if(e.getErrorCode()==1017){
                System.out.println("Невірний логін чи пароль");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


      public void closeConnection() throws SQLException{//закрываем соединение
        con.close();
    }

    public void showTable() throws SQLException{//вывод таблицы на экран

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sorts");
        System.out.println("+--+----------------+----------+----------+-------------+");
        System.out.printf("|%3s %16s %9s %6s %13s%n", "Id|", "Назва сорту |", "Сезон|","Вегетаційний період|","Середня врожайність|");
        System.out.println("+--+----------------+----------+----------+-------------+");
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.printf("|%3s %16s %10s %10s %13s%n",rs.getInt(1)+"|",rs.getString(2)+"|",rs.getInt(3)+"|",rs.getInt(4)+"|",rs.getString(5)+"|");
        }
        System.out.println("+--+----------------+----------+----------+-------------+");
        st.close();
        rs.close();
    }

    public void populationLessThan1() throws SQLException{//области с населением до 1млн
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT name_sort, FROM sorts WHERE period<250");
        System.out.print("Озимі сорти з вегетаційним періодом до 250: ");
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.print(rs.getString(1)+"("+rs.getInt(2)+");");
        }
        System.out.println();
        st.close();
        rs.close();
    }
public void avgPopulation() throws SQLException{//ищем среднее кол-во населения
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT MIN(average_yield) FROM sorts");
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println("Сорт з мінімальною і максимальною врожайністю: "+rs.getInt(1)+" чол.");
        }
        st.close();
        rs.close();
    }
    public boolean isIdReal(int id) throws SQLException{//проверяем существует ли поле с таким id в таблице
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(name_sorts) FROM sorts WHERE id="+id);
        rs1.next();
        if(rs1.getInt(1)>0) return true;
        else return false;
    }

public void edit() throws SQLException{ //редактирование данных
        int id;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        System.out.print("Введіть ID поля або 'Exit' для відміни: ");
        while(true){
            if(sc.hasNextInt()){
                id = sc.nextInt();
                if(!isIdReal(id)){
                    System.out.print("Такого ID не існує! Введіть ще раз: ");
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.print("Введіть назву колонки або 'Exit': ");
                while(true){
                    String value = null;
                    Integer intValue = null;
                    String column = sc.nextLine();
                    if(column.equalsIgnoreCase("name_sorts")||column.equalsIgnoreCase("average_yield")){
                        System.out.println("Введіть нове значення: ");
                        value=sc.nextLine();
                        st.execute("UPDATE Sorts SET "+column+" = '"+value+"' WHERE id = "+id);
                        System.out.println("Дані оновлено");
                        return;
                    }
                    else if(column.equalsIgnoreCase("sezon")||column.equalsIgnoreCase("period")){
                        System.out.println("Введіть нове значення: ");
                        while(true){
                            if(sc.hasNextInt()){
                                intValue=sc.nextInt();
                                st.execute("UPDATE Sorts SET "+column+" = '"+intValue+"' WHERE id = "+id);
                                System.out.println("Дані оновлено");
                                return;
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println("Введіть число: ");
                                sc.next();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if(column.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
                        return;
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.print("Такої колонки не існує, введіть ще раз: ");
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(sc.hasNextLine()){
                if(sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")){
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("Введіть число або 'Exit' для відміни: ");
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("Введіть число або 'Exit' для відміни: ");
                sc.next();
            }
        }       
    }public void insertData() throws SQLException{//заносим значения в таблицу
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        st.execute("insert into sorts values (null, 'Botvm','Odessa', 2395000,33314)");
        st.execute("insert into sorts values (null, 'Dnipropetrovska','Dnipro', 3285000,31923)");
        st.execute("insert into sorts values (null, 'Chernigivska','Chernigiv', 1054000,31903)");
        st.execute("insert into sorts values (null, 'Kharkivska','Kharkiv', 2696000,31418)");
        st.execute("insert into sorts values (null, 'Zhytomyrska','Zhytomyr', 1233000,29827)");
        st.execute("insert into sorts values (null, 'Polravska','Poltava', 1462000,28750)");
        st.execute("insert into sorts values (null, 'Khersonska','Kherson', 1055000,28461)");
        st.execute("insert into sorts values (null, 'Kyivska','Kyiv', 1732000,28121)");
        st.execute("insert into sorts values (null, 'Kirovogradska','Kropyvnytsky',999000,24588)");
        st.execute("insert into sorts values (null, 'Chernovytska','Chernyvtsy', 906000,8906)");
        System.out.println("Додано!");
    }

public void clearTable() throws SQLException{//удаляем все из таблицы 
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        st.execute("DELETE FROM sorts");
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Laba1 l = new Laba1();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String pass;
        boolean end = false;
        do{
            System.out.print("Введіть логін: ");
            name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Введіть пароль: ");
            pass = sc.nextLine();
        }while(!l.setConnection(name, pass));
        System.out.println("З'єднання встановлено!");
        do{
            String num;
            System.out.println("Виберіть дію:\n1 - показати таблицю\n2 - додати дані\n3 - показати області з населенням до 1млн.\n4 - показати середню кількість населення\n5 - очистити таблицю\n6 - змінити дані\n0 - вийти");
            num = sc.nextLine();

            switch(num){
                case "1": 
                    l.showTable();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    l.insertData();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    l.populationLessThan1();
                    break;
                case "4": 
                    l.avgPopulation();
                    break;
                case "5": 
                    l.clearTable();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    l.edit();
                    break;
                case "0":
                    l.closeConnection();
                    end = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Такої команди не існує!");
                    break;
            }
        }
        while(!end);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Лог покажите. И скажите на какую строку указывает. И заодно уберите из вопроса весь код, не относящийся к проблеме https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at laba1.Laba1.showTable(Laba1.java:37)
at laba1.Laba1.main(Laba1.java:178)
C:\Users\Anna\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 21 seconds)

Comment: Полные логи покажите, а не только ошибки. И что находится на строке 37?

Answer (score 0):

В методе `setConnection()` во втором `try-catch` вы ловите все `SQLException`-ы, но false возвращаете только если этот эксепшын связан с ошибкой логина-пароля (1017). Остальные вы не обрабатываете и метод при другом `SQLException` возвращает `true`. При этом `con` остается не проинициализированной (`null`). Отсюда и `NPE`.
Перенесите `return false;` ниже за фигурную скобку!

Comment: Предлагает бесконечный ввод логина и пароля, спасибо за ответ

Comment: выводите ошибку и будет видно из-за чего. Вы же ее игнорите, а только на логин-пароль реагируете